# Arquillian: Got 302 (Found)

Tags: java, spring, junit, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test a Service in my web app with JUnit and Arquillian but when I launch the test, console show the following error:

> `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test at http://127.0.0.1:8080/avisoLegalTest/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=es.dia.altatienda.service.AvisoLegalServiceTest&methodName=findActivo&cmd=event. Got 302 (Found)`

My code:

JUnit test:

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@SpringWebConfiguration
public class AvisoLegalServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    AvisoLegalService avisoLegalService;

    /**
     * <p>
     * Creates the test deployment.
     * </p>
     *
     * @return the test deployment
     */
    @Deployment
    @OverProtocol("Servlet 3.0")
    public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    System.setProperty(
        MavenSettingsBuilder.ALT_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_XML_LOCATION,
        "C:\\DEVELOPMENT_ENV\\TOOLS\\MAVEN\\apache-maven-3.3.9\\conf\\settings.xml");
    System.setProperty(MavenSettingsBuilder.ALT_USER_SETTINGS_XML_LOCATION,
        "C:\\DEVELOPMENT_ENV\\TOOLS\\MAVEN\\apache-maven-3.3.9\\conf\\settings.xml");
    return Deployments.createDeployment();
    }

    @Test
    public void findActivo() {
    try {
        AvisoLegal avisoLegal = avisoLegalService.findActivo();
        assertNotNull(avisoLegal);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        assertFalse(e.getMessage(), Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    }
}
```

My arquillian.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>
    
    <!-- Configuration to be used when the WidlFly remote profile is active -->
    <container qualifier="widlfly-remote" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">127.0.0.1</property>
            <property name="managementPort">9990</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
            <property name="password">123456</property>
        </configuration>
        
        <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
            <property name="host">127.0.0.1</property>
            <property name="port">8080</property>
        </protocol>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

My pom dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-service-deployer-spring-3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-service-integration-spring-inject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Beta3</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to test the service with Arquillian because I have activeMQ configuration (queues) over my Wildfly Server.

My project works with: Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE (Java based configuration), Java 1.8 and Wildfly 10.1.0.

Why could that be happening?

Comment: OT: Why the dependency on `org.wildfly.wildfly-server`?