# Arquillian java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test WebContext Authentication

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, ejb, jboss-arquillian

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test at http://127.0.0.1:8080/... Got 302 (Found) when I put @WebContext annotation in the operation that I want to test.

I am trying to test an operation that is presented as a EJB method and a web service with authentication using SecurityDomain. The test are working well but when I put the authentication using:

```
@WebContext(contextRoot = "apti/servicios", urlPattern = "/*", authMethod = "BASIC", transportGuarantee = "CONFIDENTIAL", secureWSDLAccess = true)
```

The WebContext Annotation working well on the wildfly 10 but when I try to implement a test case It throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error launching test at http://127.0.0.1:8080/apti/servicios/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=uy.antel.asf.automatismos.apti.core.boundary.controller.ConnectionDataBoundaryControllerTest&methodName=test_CP_DC_01&cmd=event. Got 302 (Found)
12:02:11,680 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: /apti/servicios
12:02:11,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."apti-core.war".CallBoundaryController
12:02:11,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."apti-core.war".TelelinkBoundaryController
12:02:11,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."apti-core.war".CommonPhasesBoundaryController
12:02:11,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYWS0004: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."apti-core.war".RemoteOperationBoundaryController
   at  org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor.execute(ServletMethodExecutor.java:176)
   at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletMethodExecutor$1.run(ServletMethodExecutor.java:201)
   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I have found this thread, but it does not solve the problem I face - [Arquillian: Got 302 (Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736894/arquillian-got-302-found/54027735?noredirect=1#comment94891858_54027735)

What else I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: This is arquillian client log. That does not contains much information about the error. Can you append your log on server when test run?

Comment: I fix it removing from the @WebContext annotation the contextRoot and the urlPattern attributes. The error was because it was already defined in the jboss-webservices.xml file.